# Unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name using function callback in form validation

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, continuous-integration

i'm creating my form validation called check_nim, but when i add the callback in form validation, i got error that unable to access an error message corresponding to your field name Nomor Induk Mahasiswa.(check_nim),

here's my code:

### controller user.php

```
  function daftar_act(){
    $nim = $this->input->post("nim");
    $nim = $this->security->xss_clean($nim);

    function check_nim($nim){
      if($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM akun WHERE nim ='$nim'")->num_rows() > 0){
         $this->form_validation->set_message('check_nim','NIM sudah terdaftar.');
         return false;
      }
      else{
         return true;
      }
    }

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("nim","Nomor Induk Mahasiswa","required|trim|min_length[8]|max_length[8]|callback_check_nim");
```

and this my view:

### daftar.php

```
<form action = "<?php echo base_url().'user/daftar_act'; ?> method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label>Nomor Induk Mahasiswa</label>
     <input type="number" name = "nim" class="form-control">
     <?php echo form_error("nim"); ?>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" name="daftar"> Daftar Akun </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please show us your whole daftar_act method and want to see this line in start of method $this->load->library('form_validation');

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not be setting a form validation error message for your callback `check_nim`. You need to set the proper error message using the callback function name as follows:

```
function check_nim($str)
{
    if ($str == 'test')
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_nim', 'The {field} field can not be the word "test"');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```